# AVR USART sending garbage

Tags: arduino, avr, serial, uart

I'm trying to make an ATMega328P to send serial data to my computer and print onto Putty using an arduino board to do the USB to serial conversions.  The data that's printed, however is garbage data.  I've tried changing the number of stop bits, checked the serial communications in putty, checked the Baud error rates, and have also added a delay so that the computer can read the serial data easier. Here's the code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define F_CPU 7372800
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

void printString(const char myString[]){
    uint8_t i = 8;
    while(myString[i]){
       while ((UCSR0A &(1<<UDRE0)) == 0){}//do nothing until transmission flag is set
          UDR0 = myString[i];
          i++;
    }    
}

int main(void)
{
    //--------------init usart----------------//
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0); //Enables the USART transmitter and receiver
    _delay_ms(10);
    UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00)|(USBS0<<1); //tells it to send 8bit characters (setting both USCZ01 and UCSZ00 to one)
    //now it has 2 stop bits.

    UBRR0H = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8); //loads the upper 8 bits into the high byte of the UBRR register
    UBRR0L = BAUD_PRESCALE; //loads the lower 8 bits
    //----------------------------------------//
    _delay_ms(10);


    for(;;){
    printString("Hello World!\r\n");
    }
return (0);
}
```

And the data that's displayed in putty is as follows.  First there's a bunch of this: 
  àà  àà  à   à àà  àà  àà  à.     Then there's a bunch of this:
   f,Mün$M´M,M´M$M´M,M´M,M´M,M´M 
and other similar characters.  I don't know why these are getting printed.  Thanks.

edit: here's the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf)

Comment: That looks like a case of setting the wrong baud rate. Or Setting Putty to the wrong baud rate. Are you sure your BAUD_PRESCALE is correct?

Comment: The datasheet sais that the baud prescale value needs to be equal to the system clock divided by the desired baud rate times sixteen.  Then one is subtracted.  BAUD_PRESCALE = (clock/(16(BAUD)))-1.  Entering 7372800 for the clock and 9600 for the baud rate, I get 47.  I chose this to get a 0.0% Baud rate error.  I'm not sure what would be wrong with it.  Could you elaborate?  Also, I checked putty and its set for a baud of 9600 with 2 stop bits.

Comment: The CKDIV8 fuse is set by default, make sure that it's disabled or your cpu clock will be 1/8 of what it should be and UART calculations will be wrong.

Comment: Ok, I added this line to the beginning of the main code: "CLKPR = (0<<CLKPS3)|(0<<CLKPS2)|(0<<CLKPS1)|(0<<CLKPS0);" and it still outputs the same thing (garbage data).  It doesn't seem to be the problem, but I was unaware of this the clock division.  Thanks though.

Comment: To set for clock prescaling factor it is necessary to access the CLKPR twice within 4 clock cycles. Try adding `#include <avr/power.h>` and then use `clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1);`. Refer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93209/33841.

Comment: I added it, still shows up as garbage data in putty. edit: I didnt do it twice. one sec.

Comment: Nevermind, same thing happened when I did it twice.

Comment: Use the `clock_prescale_set` macro, the two writes may not work correctly depending on the optimization.

Comment: I did use the clock_prescale_set macro.

Comment: @Cate What you're seeing is just what one would expect to see if the baud rates did not match. Have you tried setting Putty to higher or lower baud rates, to see if anything matches?

Comment: Did you by any chance forget to connect the external clock of 7.3728MHz? Moreover, setting the internal clock to 2,4 or 8MHz would do the job. There will be an error of 0.2% but that wouldn't have any significant effect in your transmission. I've used 8MHz int osc comfortably and have had no qualms.

Comment: @John Honniball  I tried setting putty to some arbitrary baud rates slightly higher and lower than 9600.  I keep getting nonsense data.

Comment: @Adithya  I set F_CPU to be 8000000 and now I get a bunch of B's and Q's as nonsense data instead of M's.  >.>

Comment: Instead of sending a string on the first go,try sending a single character and see if that works. Later evaluate if your printString function is written properly.

Comment: Did you change the FUSE bits accordingly? Just changing F_CPU will not have any effect on your oscillator settings

Answer (score 3):

This line looks suspicious:

> `UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00)|(USBS0<<1);`

You probably want that to be:

`UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00)|(1<<USBS0);`

Comment: Now the nonsense in repeating on a single line instead of filling up putty's whole screen.  Thanks for catching that.  It's a start, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Cate You have uint8_t i = 8; but shouldn't it be uint8_t i = 0; ? Zero rather than eight?

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the people at AVR Freaks and they said that F_CPU doesn't actually change the clock speed; it only is used to set the baud prescale. Since the arduino runs at 16MHz, I just had to change `F_CPU` to `16000000` and then change `uint8_t i=8;` to `uint8_t i=0;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
((UCSR0A &(1 << UDRE0)) == 0)
```

check this line on the atmega328 datasheet > UART > UART initialization code available there. I think that might be your problem, I think it should be

```
((!(UCSR0A &(1 << UDRE0)))
```

don't add == 0.